# Нужно расположить 2 div-а рядом друг с другом, двумя колонками

Tags: javascript, html, css

Пробую с помощь inline-block, когда мало текста в первом или втором блоке - всё нормально работает:

https://jsfiddle.net/L62zhh0t/1/

```css
.profi_item_left, .profi_item_right {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="profi_item">
  <div class="profi_item_left">Lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class="profi_item_right">
    <h3 class="profi_item_header">lorem</h3>
    <p class="profi_item_description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Но когда текста в первом или втором блоке много становится - блоки располагаются друг после друга, как блочные элементы:

https://jsfiddle.net/L62zhh0t/2/

```css
.profi_item_left, .profi_item_right {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="profi_item">
  <div class="profi_item_left">lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class="profi_item_right">
    <h3 class="profi_item_header">lorem</h3>
    <p class="profi_item_description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Assumenda omnis dolore consectetur ex ea recusandae deserunt incidunt fugit dicta, placeat error enim sit veniam repellendus consequuntur veritatis id sapiente officiis.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Как оптимально поступить в случае такой проблемы?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте `flexbox`:

```css
.profi_item {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<div class="profi_item">
  <div class="profi_item_left">lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class="profi_item_right">
    <h3 class="profi_item_header">lorem</h3>
    <p class="profi_item_description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Assumenda omnis dolore consectetur ex ea recusandae deserunt incidunt fugit dicta, placeat error enim sit veniam repellendus consequuntur veritatis id sapiente officiis.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Про флекс знаю, а без него вообще стоит ли для адаптивной вёрстки это делать?

Comment: Не понял вопроса. Нужно его [Flex] могущество - используйте, не суть важно адаптивность у Вас или нет.

Comment: ну просто же есть ещё решение с помощью float, насколько я знаю, так вот какое лучше будет?

Comment: Разница в том, что `float` - жук мистера Бина, а `flexbox` - последняя модель феррари. Планируете разрабатывать под старые браузеры - `float` для Вас (хотя лучше, конечно, определять такие браузеры и подгружать их стили отдельно, но не суть). В остальном же...